# _spPageContextInfo.userTimeZoneData suddenly stop working

Tags: development, office-365, jsom, timezone

I am using many _spPageContextInfo properties in my development and it works well but suddenly from last few weeks_spPageContextInfo.userTimeZoneData is not working.  
 
User has updated timezone before 2-3 months and it was working fine. 
 
Sometime it sends NULL even user has not done any activity in delve profile since long.

I am trying to ignore additional query/JSOM call to find out user timezone.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have seen couple of different office 365 (diff tenant/country/locale with other clients) and there is not issue with them.  here, in this solution we have upgrade model as well to update existing SharePoint with more features/webparts., I believe that c# csom code somehow reset _spPageContextInfo which is creating issue. still not 100% sure. appreciate if someone can add his/her view here.